# best btc node and lightning to run in lubuntu

Tags: lightning-network, client, core-lightning, bitcoin-wallet-app

I run lubuntu in my ~#missing#~. I have made multiple efforts to install umbrel, I tried it but I couldn't install to my external SSD because I run out of space. I used all the possible commands but with no success. I need another software for my lubuntu to build my node without buying more hardware if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Mh yes, this is one of the tricky parts of the lightning network! Sorry about that

In my early years, I worked on this problem and how to solve it with core lightning, and I came out with a solution that used the https://github.com/clightning4j/btcli4j plugin to fetch the bitcoin data in a different way (including the Rest API, so you do not need a bitcoin node)

You can find the description in [my article](https://medium.com/@vincenzopalazzo/run-a-cln-node-with-clightning4j-tools-on-a-tiny-vps-60f2a4779fa7) that uses the docker to run all the architecture https://github.com/clightning4j/clightning4j-node

Otherwise, if you want to run core lightning without docker, you can just install the plugin and run it with the command `lightningd --disable-plugin bcli`